# How to find run time of a program from commmand line?

Tags: command-line

I just ran a program and wish to know how much time it took to execute it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `time [programname]`.

Example:

```
host:~$ time dmesg

[massive gob of dmesg output]

real    0m2.630s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.030s
```